# dynamic js with phantomjs in local html file

Tags: php, d3.js, phantomjs, server, gearman

I am building diagram with D3.js that use big data.. now rather than bring data to client side I decide to build this diagram on server and show image to client... 
Project on PHP , Use Gearman for threading , And phantomjs for capturing image ...

now 1 ) currently phantomjs command line tool give image only when this diagram html code is running on some where like localhost or etc.  **SO How can I get this image without run that code on server**

2) now if i use csv file with d3.js without run it on some server it will not allow to read it.. **so alternate way to read this csv files with local html page**

3) the csv that i use is dynamic if i use static page than I have update that part with php code .. But while threads are running async if i update file for one and another thread use it that may create issue ...  **some parallel mechanism which use some package and with one dynamic js or attr .**

Comment: What csv file? Where does come from? What should the content be? How should it be transformed? What does it have to do with the rendering in PhantomJS?

Comment: Please describe your architecture properly. What processes run are other processes and which concurrently. What are they supposed to do and what are they doing? What does *"some package and with one dynamic js or attr"* mean?

Comment: csv file is build from some php code based on dynamic query it holds results ... 

now this will work same for more than  3-4 users in parallel on server with gearman plugin ...
at the end of this function i will use this data to build diagram,here diagram code will be same but the csv will different   ... SO for each user this csv will be different based on some unique name or id that will follow form the parallel process ... So for each use that should be new csv ...

Answer (score 0):

> currently phantomjs command line tool give image only when this diagram html code is running on some where like localhost or etc. **SO How can I get this image without run that code on server?**

Regardless where it comes from, PhantomJS consumes html+css+js. If the server simply serves static files, then open those files with the file-URIs. If this is generated through the server, why would you find another way to generate the same output? It is pointless to do the same task in another way.

> now if i use csv file with d3.js without run it on some server it will not allow to read it.. *so alternate way to read this csv files with local html page*

You probably need to use a file-URIs to reference resources on a relative path.

Comment: if we use d3.csv without any server it will return cross domain origin error to read file..

Comment: Use `--local-to-remote-url-access=true` when running it, but then you need the server running to do this.